# How to delete an entry from queryset in django html template without refresing page?

Tags: javascript, django, django-models

On my HTML template, I am printing a list of my QuerySet that I passed from `views.py` in Django. I want users to delete an entry from the list without refreshing the page. How do I do that?

urls.py - `path("del_trans/<int:trans_num>", views.delete_transaction, name="delete_transaction")`

views.py

```
def delete_transaction(request, trans_id):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

    transaction = Transaction.objects.get(ruser=user, id=trans_id)

    transaction.delete()

    return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

trans.html

```
<tr id="trans-{{t.id}}">
    <td>{{ t.name }}</td>
        
    <td><button class="btn" onclick="delete_trans({{t.id}})"><span style="cursor:pointer;
            color:blue;
            text-decoration:underline;">Delete</span></button></td>
</tr>
```

index.js

```
function delete_trans(id) {
    fetch(`/del_trans/${id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            trans_id: id
        })
    });

    document.querySelector('#trans-' + id).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: could you share your views ,your template and your model ?

Comment: Using AJAX, send a request to a new view that manages the deletion.

Comment: Btw, I just watched your code. The REST standard request method for deletions is DELETE.

Comment: @oz19 what is this DELETE and REST and where/how do I use them?

Comment: DELETE is one of the verbs you can use in request methods (like GET, POST, etc.). REST is just a software architecture style (but it's not strictly required to apply it, don't worry). There's a bunch of info on the internet and it's an interesting reading for devs ;)

Comment: I would highly recommend using something like Django REST Framework, as the potential security holes here are massive. Right now, for example, a bad actor could hit your endpoints with sequential transaction IDs and delete everything. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: It is not possible without refresh delete entry, you will have to use ajax..

Comment: It's complicated, django is a server side framework which means that you cannot change a page content unless you reload it, if you want to change a page without reloading it you have to use javascript and use django just for the data.